# Get keyDown event for an NSTextField

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, events, keydown

In xcode last version, I am trying to get the keyDown event of an NSTextField.
However, despite following multiple tutorials on the internet (delegates, controllers...), I still can't receive it.

Any easy hint for me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Due to how field editors work, it's a bit complex. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 14):

I got sick of all the non answers to do it some other way people so I put my nose down and figured out a way to make this work.  This isn't using keydown event directly but it is using the keydown in the block.  And the behavior is exactly what I wanted.

Subclass the text field

.h

```
@interface LQRestrictedInputTextField : NSTextField
```

.m

In the become first responder setup a local event

```
static id eventMonitor = nil;

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    BOOL okToChange = [super becomeFirstResponder];
    if (okToChange) {
        [self setKeyboardFocusRingNeedsDisplayInRect: [self bounds]];

        if (!eventMonitor) {
            eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

                NSString *characters = [event characters];
                unichar character = [characters characterAtIndex:0];
                NSString *characterString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character];

                NSArray *validNonAlphaNumericArray = @[@" ",@"(",@")",@"[",@"]",@":",@";",@"\'",@"\"",@".",@"<",@">",@",",@"{",@"}",@"|",@"=",@"+",@"-",@"_",@"?",@"#",
                                                   @(NSDownArrowFunctionKey),@(NSUpArrowFunctionKey),@(NSLeftArrowFunctionKey),@(NSRightArrowFunctionKey)];

                if([[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character] || character == NSCarriageReturnCharacter || character == NSTabCharacter || character == NSDeleteCharacter || [validNonAlphaNumericArray containsObject:characterString ] ) { //[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]
                }  else {
                    NSBeep();
                    event=nil;
                }
                return event;
            } ];

        }
    }
    NSLog(@"become first responder");
    return okToChange;
}
```

remove the event once the textfield editing ends

Also if you're using ARC I noticed you might need to assign the textview string to the stringValue.  I nslog'd the stringValue and the value was retained.  Without the nslog I had to assign the notification object string to the stringValue to keep it from getting released.

```
-(void) textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSEvent removeMonitor:eventMonitor];
    eventMonitor = nil;

    NSTextView *textView=[notification object];
    self.stringValue=textView.string;
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm. I just put the remove event call in the resignFirstResponder method to mirror the adding placement

Answer (score 5):

You can subclass NStextField and use keyUp that works for NSTextField.

in .h

```
@interface MyTextField : NSTextField <NSTextFieldDelegate>
```

in .m

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Pressed key in NStextField!");
}
```

Comment: You can just use the delegate method instead of sub-classing. You also need to set the NSTextField's delegate to File's Owner. That's the most simple way, at least.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asks for keyDown

Comment: Jamie, KeyDown is another delegate function.

Answer (score -3):

Add UITextFieldDelegate to your .h like this

```
@interface ViewController :  UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

Then you can use this to detect every key press in a text field

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Return YES to allow the character that was pressed to be inserted into the field but you can add whatever code you need in here.