# Detecting arrow/enter keys when editing NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I couldn't find anything up to date that solve this issue.
How can I monitor something like arrow key presses while editing an `NSTextField`?

From what I looked up:
- `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` functions are not called (and I wouldn't know how to use them)
- `NSTextFieldDelegate` functions don't list something that would work here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recognize if user has pressed arrow key while editing NSTextField swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579092/recognize-if-user-has-pressed-arrow-key-while-editing-nstextfield-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your text field's delegate:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Add the following inheritance for protocols:

`class MyTextField : NSTextFieldDelegate, NSControlTextEditingDelegate { ...`

And implement the following:

```
   func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
    if commandSelector == #selector(moveUp(_:)) {
        ...
    } else if commandSelector == #selector(moveDown(_:)) {
        ...
    } else if commandSelector == #selector(insertNewline(_:)) {
        ...
    }
    return true
}
```

There are more in depth explanations in this link [Recognize if user has pressed arrow key while editing NSTextField swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579092/recognize-if-user-has-pressed-arrow-key-while-editing-nstextfield-swift)

Answer (score 0):

[`keyDown` doesn't seem to work with NSTextFields (it does for `NSTextView`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8868890/981049), so what I did on my side was subclass either `NSTextField` or `ViewController` and add these methods:

```
import Cocoa

class MyTextField: NSTextField
{    
    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("MyTextField keyUp key is %ld", event.keyCode)

        super.keyUp(with: event)            
    }
}

class MyTextView: NSTextView
{
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {

        print("MyTextView keyDown key is %ld", event.keyCode)

        super.keyDown(with: event)
    }    
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("ViewController keyUp key is %ld", event.keyCode)

        super.keyUp(with: event)
    }
}
```